# PsExec "The handle is invalid"

Tags: windows, psexec, remote-login

When I try to `PsExec` to a remote machine using `PsExec \\machine -u domain\user -p pass` `PsExec` shows the following error message:

```
The handle is invalid.
Couldn't access machine:
Completed in 0.426s
```

However `domain\user` can remote login to `\\machine` with no problem. Any ideas how can I let `domain\user` PsExec into that machine as well.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:
Start > Run > Type \machine\c$
In the dialog box that opens type domain\user and password

If you can't log in to the administrative share (c$) of the remote machine with that particular user ID, it means it does not have administrative rights, and therefore, no permission to execute on that machine.

If you can log in, try running PSList first, to verify that the process handle exists.

Comment: c$ is not the administrative share it's a drive share...  \admin$ is the administrative share.

Comment: Actually, C$ (or every volume letter followed by a $) is considered an administrative share: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_share#Share_names

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you have reached the maximum number of connections allowed by the "Server" windows service, try restarting it.

You can see the number of sessions in use with this command:

```
net statistics server
```

It happened me in Windows 7 Professional to have lots of active sessions and was giving the "The handle is invalid." message in Psexec

Answer (score 1):

Restarting Netlogon service helped to solve my issue

Comment: Can you please add some details, clarifications

Comment: How did you restart the service?

Comment: Solved it for me too - on your server Press WIN + R, enter services.msc, select "Netlogon" and press Restart.

Answer (score 0):

Open "Registry Editor" on your remote server
Navigate to:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
Add a new DWORD value:
LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy
Set LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy =  1
Reboot the remote machine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).